# Extracting text from a PDF in python when the pdf has images and tables

Tags: python, pdf, text, extract, pypdf

I'm trying to extract text from a pdf using python. I tried to use PyPDF2 but it seems to only work if the pdf is simple basic text and nothing else. Is there anything else that can help me extract text from PDFs?

Comment: If you wanna extract tables specifially, you can use https://pypi.org/project/excalibur-py/ excalibur python

Comment: Asking for library/software recommendations is off-topic, see [help/on-topic].

Comment: "Simply basic text and nothing else" is already very difficult and may fail for seemingly perfectly normal ("simple") documents. TLDR: when attempting to extract text from PDFs, lower your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Try using pdfreader (https://pdfreader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#how-to-browse-document-pages). There's a module in the library called SimplePDFViewer that extracts only the text from a certain page of a pdf document.

Example:

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer
pdf='test.pdf'
fn=open(pdf, 'rb')
viewer=SimplePDFViewer(fn)
viewer.render()
text="".join(viewer.canvas.strings)
pg_1=text
```

It extracts the text from page 1 of my pdf into a string. Output:

```
pg_1
Out[79]: '   Sequoia Mortgage Trust 2020-3 March 19, 2020                          
Analytical Contacts:  Jay Wang, Director jay.wang@kbra.com, (646) 731-1220  Jack 
Kahan, Senior Managing Director jkahan@kbra.com, (646) 731-2486        Armine 
Karajyan, Associate Director akarajyan@kbra.com, (646) 731-1210  Fei Han, Associate  
fhan@kbra.com, (646) 731-2342 Sequoia Mortgage  Trust 2020-3 Structured Finance RMBS 
New Issue Report '
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and how to get text from multiple pages?